# Howto start qooxdoo in Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, qooxdoo

I have now learned how to create a nodeJS server. 
This is my simple server (synchronous, I know):

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var qx = require("qooxdoo");

 function onRequest(request, response){    
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received ");

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text-plain"});
    response.end();  
 }

 http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
 console.log("Server has started");   
}

exports.start = start;
```

Now, for my training purposes, I would like to implement and start my Qooxdoo showcase.

Answer (score 0):

The qooxdoo node server can act as backend data provider - as a [REST service](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/communication/rest.html) or [RPC service](http://manual.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/communication/rpc.html).

For the client side application you can generate a separate qooxdoo desktop project and expose the compiled files through a static file server like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [node-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static)